# Umbraco 6 deployed to production, pages render blank

Tags: iis, deployment, umbraco, iis-express

I am using Umbraco 6 in Visual Studio 2012. I made my project using MVC 4.0 and have been developing my project locally within Visual Studio. I am at a point where I would like to deploy this to my server in IIS 7.5. For some reason after copying the files to my server and seting the site up in IIS, my website will only display a blank white page no matter which Url I put in.

The most puzzling thing, is that I can still get the backend part of Umbraco by using this Url:

umbracodev."enterURL".org/umbraco/

I then get into the backend of Umbraco and can view all of my content pages, templates, etc.

Does anyone know why I would be getting blank pages even though everything appears to be there on the Umbraco backend?

The only thing I can think of is the fact that visual studio 2012 uses IIS express and when deploying to my server I used IIS 7.5

Answer (score 6):

SOLVED! My problem was with publishing from Visual Studio. I initially published the project and moved the published project to IIS. For some reason, this caused a large majority of my files to simply not be there. After moving the files over that weren't "published" everything worked fine!

After Looking in App_Data/Logs I found a message saying that the necessary template files could not be located. This lead me to my solution!

Comment: Yep - this was it for me as well.  Publishing from Visual Studio excluded a lot of files, in this case the blank/white screen was due to missing all of the files in the \Views directory.  Thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any HTML source when you view the source?  If so, I saw the same thing recently that turned out to be an unterminated `<script>` block in one of my templates.

Comment: No. I get a response code 200 with content length 0. If I go to a page that isn't set up in Umbraco I get a 404 error.